# Массив и его перебор

Tags: vba

Есть задача - написать макрос для MS Excel. Макросу нужно указать папку, а он в этой папке должен найти все файлы Эксель и проделать с ними опреации:

- Открыть книгу
- Скопировать определенные ячейки
- Вставить их содержимое в другую книгу
- Закрыть книгу

В общем, собрать из всех файлов одну таблицу. 
В отличие от привычного Питона, в ВБА не понятно абсолютно всё.
Читал справки на офсайте Майкрософт, но там почему-то дают ложные описания.

1. Как создать пустой массив, чтобы в него влазило любое количество элементов?
   Пробовал `Dim ExcelFiles() As Variant`, но в этот массив ничего нельзя добавить. Если указать длину, то работает, но хотелось бы узнать как создать именно пустой массив.
2. Как узнать кол-во элементов (длину) массива? Ответы нашел только расплывчатые. Аналог `Array.length` в ЯваСкрипте, например.
3. Как работают циклы?
   Есть такой фрагмент:

`For j = 0 To UBound(ExcelFiles)
    Workbooks.Open (ExcelFiles(j))
    Workbooks(ExcelFiles(j)).Close SaveChanges:=False
Next j`

Длина массива `ExcelFiles` = 3, но фактически цикл выполняет только `Workbooks.Open (ExcelFiles(j))` для первого элемента массива. Никаких ошибок не выдаёт. Просто делает вид, как будто всё сделано правильно.

Ну и самое главное: с помощью чего его можно отладить?

Comment: Вид-Макросы-Начать запись... Делаете свои манипуляции. Останавливаете запись, смотрите на код записанного макроса, меняете что нужно. Профит.

Comment: Не пойдет. Запись предусмотрена для конкретных шагов и массив со всеми именами файлов в произвольной папке он не запишет

Comment: **"меняете что нужно"** Вы пишите с нуля, тем временем после записи болванки макроса, большая часть вопросов должна отпасть. И появятся более конкретные вопросы типа "как из vba получить список файлов в папке?" или "как открыть диалог выбора файлов/директорий из vba?" которые гуглятся наверняка.

Comment: Прочитайте мой вопрос еще раз, посмотрите на ответ ниже. Подумайте.

Comment: Всегда рад помочь. Держитесь там...

Comment: Могу показать процедуру определения количества файлов Excel в папке и процедуру извлечения данных. Но как посмотрят модераторы? Это уже не по теме. Менять название? Но вопрос, который в названии сейчас, тоже неплохой и может быть полезен. Может быть, стоит создать отдельный вопрос?

Comment: Спасибо, но это самому удалось понять. Рабочую заготовку выбора папки нашел на форумах. Сначала я собирал все пути с именами файлов `FileItem.Path` в массив, затем и спользуя Ваш ответ я начал перебирать их. Кое-что началось получаться, теперь надо настраивать. `Скажите, как активировать лист по его имени?`

Comment: Worksheets("имя").Activate Лучше применять внутренние имена листов. Вопрос выходит за рамки темы.

Comment: Не сильно по теме, но если знаете питон, то почему бы не сделать на нём? Если файлы `xlsx` и нет каких-то сильно сложных манипуляций, то с помощью `openpyxl` мне кажется это проще организовать.

Comment: Я б с удовольствием, но по надуманным причинам, мне отказали в установке интерпретатора на рабочий комп. Есть только офис с vba

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Массив можно указать минимальный:

   ReDim ArrData (1 To 2, 1 To 1)

и добавлять в него элементы, но с сохранением данных можно изменять только последнюю размерность:

```
 ReDim Preserve ArrData (1 To 2, 1 To 5)
```

2. Длина массива (первая размерность - по умолчанию, можно не указывать):

   UBound(ArrData)

   UBound(ArrData,2)
3. Не цикл виноват. Книга - это объект и в переменную нужно заносить как объект:

   ```
   Set wBook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=j) 

   With wBook
       ' действия в книге
       .Close
   End With
   ```

   ---

С помощью чего производить отладку?

а) доп. программы;

б) очень полезно первой строкой в модуле иметь

```
Option Explicit
```

Установить через *Tools-Options*

Отлавливает ошибки синтаксиса, необъявленные переменные, дублирование переменных или имен процедур. Оч-ч-чень полезная штучка.

Пример: "*wBook*" "*wBoоk*" - одна буква "о" кириллическая. Такую ошибку долго можно искать, *Option Explicit* на нее укажет сразу.

в) *Debug.Print*

В нужных местах кода с помощью оператора можно взять данные, параметры, значения переменных, промежуточные вычисления и проч. и вывести полученное в окно *Immediate* (показать окно - *Gtrl+G* или через меню *View*)